# kafka: different offsets for one topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I've faced with strange behavior of getOffset for kafka topic (hope,it is not strange and I just don't understand something)

Offsets from console:
first offset = 8625

```
./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list kaf001:9092,kaf002:9092 --topic topic1 --time -2 --partitions 0
```

last offset = 16789145

```
./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list kaf001:9092,kaf002:9092 --topic topic1 --time -1 --partitions 0
```

Offsets from java code: 0 and 16780520 corresponding. I'm using artefact kafka_2.10:0.8.1.1

So, offsets returned by java differ from offsets from console. But

```
16780520 - 0 = 16789145 - 8625.
```

So, the count of messages is the same.

Why do they differ?

Comment: Was your consumer constantly consuming data while you fetched these offsets? In that case the offset would be updated continuously and hence you the difference.

Comment: No, I've stopped all consumers/producers before requesting offsets via command line and java code.

Comment: Can you provide the java code here as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in case of **split-brain** in zookeeper:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1209

Brokers connect to different leaders and the system becomes inconsistent.